# How to define API in WSO2 ESB -

Tags: wso2-esb

I have the following two APIs that I need to define in WSO2 ESB.

```
http://server:port/account?account_number=1
http://server:port/account/account_by_sp?site=1&sp=2
```

What's the proper way (i.e. one API with multiple resources or separate APIs) to define these in WSO2 ESB, so that they can be individually called by clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a single API and use a switch or a filter mediator and send it to either of the two URIs depending upon the conditions(ie. what parameters you have recieved).

Comment: That's how it was implemented finally. It was straightforward implementation in the In sequence however, depending on what happens thereafter, the Out sequence implementation can be, not as straightforward. Thanks rohan.

Comment: you are welcome...
for the outSequence part: you could use a flag in the inSequence(using property mediator) and check its value in the outsequence.